# Specify rancher-compose.yml file same as it's done for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rancher

It's possible to specify a `rancher-compose.yml` file for `rancher-compose up` command same as with `docker-compose -f custom.yml`

```
$ rancher-compose up --help
Usage: rancher-compose up [OPTIONS]

Bring all services up

Options:
   --pull, -p                         Before doing the upgrade do an image pull on all hosts that have the image already
   -d                                 Do not block and log
   --upgrade, -u, --recreate          Upgrade if service has changed
   --force-upgrade, --force-recreate  Upgrade regardless if service has changed
   --confirm-upgrade, -c              Confirm that the upgrade was success and delete old containers
   --rollback, -r                     Rollback to the previous deployed version
   --batch-size value                 Number of containers to upgrade at once (default: 2)
   --interval value                   Update interval in milliseconds (default: 1000)
```

I dont see it possible but maybe is there a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rancher-compose -f` option is available.

Check [this](https://github.com/rancher/rancher-compose#usage) out.

I see its even [available](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.1/en/cattle/rancher-compose/commands/) in older 1.x version of rancher.

**NOTE**: I guess `-f` option is not for `rancher-compose up` but for just `rancher-compose` command. But the end result is same as it allows to have alternate compose files.

Comment: ah I see, totally missed that